# Wordpress page showing content but admin for page is blank

Tags: wordpress

What would cause a wordpress page to show content on the front end but be empty in the admin.

I am just taking over a someone elses site. I am trying to import the pages onto my server but I am only getting blank pages on both the front end and the back end.

Posts are showing correctly. It just most pages.

Comment: Add this to your theme's `index.php`, it should give you a better idea of what is happening:

`<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

?>`

Answer (score 3):

Sackling..

The problem is in charset of db. Open wp-config.php file and just change charset to utf8 & comment the old one.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Thanks

Comment: I ran into this issue while working on a very very old WP site and this answer made me realize the `wp-config.php` was missing a few of the standard wordpress defined constants. If anyone finds the above answer does not solve the issue be sure `define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );` is also defined. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Look to the right side on the edit page screen, "Page Attributes" Under Page attributes look for "Page template". That probably is the reason for it to show content. Developers create page templates, add the content they want to show directly in the page template and set that page template to Wordpress Page.

A page template is basically a php file added to your active Theme's directory. You could just ftp into the server and see the files, you'll have to look into each .php file as the name of the file doesn't really matter. It could be anything.
However the page template's name which you saw on the edit page screen's dropdown, should be written in the php file's header.

So if your page template is "Custom Home", someone could have made a file called home-new.php but when you open the file you'll see something like this

```
<?php 
/*
 * Template Name: Custom Home
 */
 get_header();?>
```

That probably is where the content is coming from.

[**CODEX**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)